# Content no load (jquery mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application with jQuery mobile and json bring data. 
I have a problem loading content when I click on a button but if I enter directly to link the content is there.

Please, look:

if you click on any image it shows a page without content: `http://www.example.com.ar/catalogoar/`

But if you enter `http://www.example.com.ar/catalogoar/arma_ampliada.html?id_arma=1` the content is there.

I can't find the problem. I already try with

```
$("#tabla_arma").table('refresh');
```

Comment: Don't just link to your website. Atleast add some relevant code you have problem with.

Comment: I don't know what is the code fails :S. I just make a link to another page and show content on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, learn how jQuery Mobile works before you post any more related questions. I am not trying to attack you but people here don't like this kind of questions.

To be able to solve this problem you need to understand how jQuery Mobile page handling works, and you can't solve this problem.

When jQuery Mobile handles pages only first **HTML** files is fully loaded into the **DOM**, all intermediate files are loaded only partially. When I say partially I mean **HEAD** will be stripped away and only FIRST **data-role="page"** will be loaded.

So if you have 2 pages, for example lets say first one is called **index.html** and second one is called **arma_ampliada.html**. When second page is initialized only content inside data-role="page" <div> will load into the DOM, everything else is going to get discarded, including HEAD javascript you need to load your data.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**, you will also found solutions.

Your **arma_ampliada.html** page should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Catálogo de Armas</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/listview-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function()
        {
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';
        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/cordova.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="demo-page" class="my-page">
    <script>
        var armas;

        function obtenerArmaAmpliada(id_arma){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: {'id_arma' : id_arma},
                dataType : 'jsonp',
                url: 'service/datos.php?jsoncallback=?',
                success:function(data){
                    armas = data.armas;
                    mostrarArmas();
               },
               error: function() {
                 alert("error");
               }
            });
        }


        function mostrarArmas ()
        {
            $("#arma_ampliada").html('');
            $.each(armas, function(indice, receta) 
            {
                $("#arma_ampliada").append('<tr><td><a href="arma_ampliada.html?id_arma='+receta.id+'"><img src="'+receta.foto+'" class="ui-li-thumb" ><h2>'+receta.marca+'</h2><p>'+receta.modelo+'</p></a></td></tr>');
            });
            $("#tabla_arma").table('refresh');
        }

        $(function(){
            var Url = location.href;
            Url = Url.replace(/.*\?(.*?)/,"$1");
            Variables = Url.split ("&");
            for (i = 0; i < Variables.length; i++) 
            {
                Separ = Variables[i].split("=");
                eval ('var '+Separ[0]+'="'+Separ[1]+'"');
            }

            obtenerArmaAmpliada(id_arma);
        });
    </script>
    <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <h1>Cat&aacute;logo de Armas</h1>
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Opciones</a>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Marcas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Calibre</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tipo</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="tabla_arma">
            <table id="arma_ampliada">

            </table>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to learn with practice but in some parts i don't know how to go.
Sorry if my question upset, I couldn't find the solution in google. Your link helped me understand my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry, you didn't upset me, just be careful next time, people here don't like this kind of questions. I don't mind as long as I can help. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take your advice for the next time =)